# confused about linq and IEnumerable or IList

Tags: linq-to-sql

Can someone explain why i get an 'no translations to sql' error in 'results' statement  if GetAddresses() returns IList but not if it returns IEnumerable?

```
var addresses= GetAddresses(dataContext);

results = results.Where(r => r.People.Any(a => Addresses.Contains(a)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
 results = results.Where(r => r.People.Any(a => Addresses.Contains(a))).ToList();
```